# Apache Spark program not receiving messages from Google Cloud Pubsub

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a simple Java program that reads messages from a Google Cloud Pubsub topic and prints them. It works correctly when I run the program as a standalone, but it fails to receive messages when run using spark-submit.

1. Do programs launched using spark-submit have to follow a different structure in general? My program doesn't do any Spark related stuff as of now, but I'll be adding it later.
2. Are there working examples of Spark + Cloud Pubsub integration? I came across a library called Apache Bahir, but is it a must to use a library like that?

The code for my example can be found here: https://github.com/pramodbiligiri/pubsub-spark

Comment: Do you have some connection error? Are you creating the pull subscription when your job start or do you reuse an existing one?

Comment: There are no errors. Program just hangs. I think there is some chatter between the client and server looking at the network traffic, but it's encrypted and the Subscriber doesn't do anything after starting to listen for messages.

I create the pull subscription when the program launches. There is no Spark "job" as such - it's just a simple main() function.


The code for the entire thing is here - https://github.com/pramodbiligiri/pubsub-spark/blob/main/src/main/java/spark/pubsub/example/PubsubConsumer.java#L21-L49

Comment: What is the frequency of message creation in the topic? Has a message been created after the spark job creation?

Comment: I've tried that. Didn't make a difference. I only created a handful of messages though, not dozens! Strange part is that old and new messages get delivered from Pubsub when outside of Spark :|

Comment: In fact, messages don't live in a topic but in a subscription. If, when you publish, no subscription exists, the message is lost. If you create a subscription, but no new message arrives in the Topic, you won't have any message in the subscription. That's why my question: did you publish a message in the topic AFTER having the spark job listening to the fresh newly created subscription?

Comment: Yeah, actually I did publish messages that reached the already-created subscription successfully. The problem turned out to be how I was using the Spark API. See my self answer to this question below. Thanks for trying to help and debug this!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. It needed a SparkSession to be instantiated and wait for termination signal from the user. In my case I used a StreamingContext - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html